# Deploying/Migration an application from JBoss 4.2.3GA to 7.1.1GA

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

Deploying/Migration an application from JBoss 4.2.3GA to 7.1.1GA

I am new to JBoss AS 7. I have been using JBoss 4.2.3 for years and now our organization is finally moving towards JBoss 7.1.1. So, I have started with a quite simple application in order to touch base the migration. Application is a EAR file, in which a EJB JAR and a WAR file are present.

Deploying the application as it was in JBoss 4.2.3GA, a marker file is created under APP351.ear.isdeploying, and the changes to APP351.ear.failed. I got an error in server.log:

Log (only showing WARN and ERROR rows):

```
2014-06-10 13:29:50,091 WARN  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011600: AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO. If your platform is Linux, install LibAIO to enable the AIO journal

2014-06-10 13:30:05,108 WARN  [org.jboss.metadata.parser.jboss.JBossAppMetaDataParser] (MSC service thread 1-6) loader-repository element in jboss-app.xml is deprecated and has been ignored

JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.security.security-domain.AuthUser (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./APP351.realm] 

2014-06-10 13:30:32,564 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.web.deployment.default-host./APP351.realmjboss.security.security-domain.AuthUserMissing[jboss.web.deployment.default-host./APP351.realmjboss.security.security-domain.AuthUser]"]}}}
```

My application specifications:

- Struts 1.3.5 (in the web project (WAR file))
- EJB3.0 (the one from the container)
- jcifs-1.3.17 for authentication

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="APP351EJB">
      <jta-data-source>java:/APP351_DS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

jboss-app.xml (I know it has been ignored by JBoss 7.1.1 as it is now deprecated)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-app PUBLIC
      "-//JBoss//DTD J2EE Application 1.4//EN"
      "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-app_4_2.dtd">

<jboss-app>
    <loader-repository>
        APP351:archive=APP351.ear

        <loader-repository-config>
            java2ParentDelegation=false
        </loader-repository-config>
  </loader-repository>
</jboss-app>
```

standalone-full.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">

    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.cmp"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jacorb"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxr"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsr77"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.messaging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.osgi"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
    </extensions>


    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <management-interfaces>
            <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
            </native-interface>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
    </management>


    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:cmp:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:/APP351_DS" pool-name="APP351_DS_pool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://mydatabaseserver:5435/mydatabase</connection-url>
                    <driver>postgresql-driver</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>MY_LOGIN</user-name>
                        <password>MY_PW</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="postgresql-driver" module="org.postgresql">
                        <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="db2-driver" module="com.ibm.db2">
                        <driver-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</driver-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" auto-deploy-exploded="false"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2">
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </stateless>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>
            <mdb>
                <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="hornetq-ra"/>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </mdb>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>
                <cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/>
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <file-passivation-store name="file"/>
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default">
                <data-store path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="10"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
            <iiop enable-by-default="false" use-qualified-name="false"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.2" default-cache-container="hibernate">
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jacorb:1.1">
            <orb>
                <initializers transactions="spec" security="on" />
            </orb>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxr:1.1">
            <connection-factory jndi-name="java:jboss/jaxr/ConnectionFactory"/>
            <properties/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.1">
            <show-model value="true"/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.0">
            <jpa default-datasource=""/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsr77:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.0">
            <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
            </mail-session>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.1">
            <hornetq-server>
                <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
                <journal-file-size>102400</journal-file-size>
                <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

                <connectors>
                    <netty-connector name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                    <netty-connector name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                        <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    </netty-connector>
                    <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                </connectors>

                <acceptors>
                    <netty-acceptor name="netty" socket-binding="messaging"/>
                    <netty-acceptor name="netty-throughput" socket-binding="messaging-throughput">
                        <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                        <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                    </netty-acceptor>
                    <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                </acceptors>

                <security-settings>
                    <security-setting match="#">
                        <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                        <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                    </security-setting>
                </security-settings>

                <address-settings>
                    <address-setting match="#">
                        <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                        <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                        <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                        <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
                        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                    </address-setting>
                </address-settings>

                <jms-connection-factories>
                    <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                        </entries>
                    </connection-factory>
                    <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                            <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                        </entries>
                    </connection-factory>
                    <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                        <transaction mode="xa"/>
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                        </entries>
                    </pooled-connection-factory>
                </jms-connection-factories>
</hornetq-server>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.2" activation="lazy">
            <properties>
                <property name="org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning">
                    1
                </property>
            </properties>
            <capabilities>
                <capability name="javax.servlet.api:v25"/>
                <capability name="javax.transaction.api"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.felix.log" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.jboss.osgi.logging" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.felix.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.jboss.as.osgi.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
            </capabilities>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1">
            <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">

            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>

                        <login-module code="RealmUsersRoles" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-users.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-roles.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="realm" value="ApplicationRealm"/>
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>                     
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>

                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>

        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.1">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.1">
            <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>
    </profile>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        <socket-binding name="jacorb" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/>
        <socket-binding name="jacorb-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/>
        <socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/>
        <socket-binding name="messaging-throughput" port="5455"/>
        <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>

</server>
```

Important troubleshooting info:

- Datasource is correct
- Permissions on database are correct
- I have compared our standalone-full.xml configuration with the original one from JBoss 7.1 and it is almost the same except the datasources, JDBC drivers and date format

I am trying to understand that error but I can't find anything about "realmjboss.security.security-domain.AuthUserMissing" or even "AuthUserMissing". It is indeed an authentication issue or a security issue, but I can't find any information or guide about that specific subject.

Any hints about the migration from JBoss 4.2.3 to 7.1.1 would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Charles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Migrating from 4 to 7 is a very big step, so you might want to look at at least 2 migration steps (4 to 5 and then 5 to 7).

[Here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7) is the "official" guide for the latter and [here](http://jvalentino.blogspot.de/2011/12/upgrading-jboss-4-to-jboss-5-with-java.html) is one example for the 1st step. Concerning your specific error, you might want to look at security realms [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Security+Realms).

Comment: Thank you for the resources. Migrating from 4 to 5 is not an option. We don't have control on JBoss version in our organization. Will look into that. I was quite surprised to find absolutely nothing on Google about the error message I got though...

Comment: You don't need to have a running JBoss 5 (though it would be of help to have it at least locally if possible for testing), it's just uncommon to migrate from 4 directly to 7, that's why you don't find much information about it, so you follow guides for 2 or 3 smaller steps. I did find an [article](http://www.marcusschiesser.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/JM_10_11_Schiesser_JBoss-Migration.pdf) exactly about that in a German magazine, but I don't know if that is useful for you.

Comment: Can you give us some more explanation like why we need to to take baby steps and not directly target the latest version which is JBOSS AS7? Because I am trying to migrate an application from JBOSS AS4 and can't find solid reasoning behind your answer.

Comment: @VirendraSinghRathore There were a lot of changes between version 5 and 7 - so while it is of course possible to directly migrate from 4 to 7, it is easier to take the 2 steps, since RedHat provides migration documentation only from one version to the next. By the way, when you speak of "latest version", are you really talking about JBoss AS7 or do you mean JBoss EAP 7, since this is something different. JBoss AS 7 is an old community version which is replaced by the WildFly AS, which is available in version 11, EAP 7 on the other hand is the latest commercial version.